# Spring boot configs in S3 - AWS beanstalk

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-boot, configuration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have  aspring boot application running in AWS beanstalk. It currently reads the properties from `src/main/resources/application.properties` file. I want to override those configuration by providing the properties as a file in `S3`. So I created a file in `S3` at `s3://my-bucket/some_dir/application.properties`. In the beanstalk application, I provided the following setting in **Software Configuration**.

`spring.config.location` with value `s3://my-bucket/some_dir/application.properties`.

Restarted the app but I still see the old values. I had followed the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As pointed out by @Strelok, this approach won't work. I can perhaps add scripts to `.ebextensions` to download the file from S3 and then read it, but that would require redeploying the jar each time I want to update the configs. That's not a use case for my application. Instead, I am now reading the S3 file in a method in the application and loading the properties. That way, I can call the method while the app is running and reload configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just won't work. Spring doesn't just understand s3:// URLs. Create a startup script for your app that first downloads the file then passes it to your app with `--spring.config.locations`.